# inclusion of interaction terms in bestglm in R

Tags: r, glm, interaction, cross-validation, model-fitting

I would like to use the delete-d cross-validation technique available in the R package bestglm. I have a binomial response variable (species presence/absence) and 11 predictor variables that are continuous or have levels and I am treating them in the analysis as continuous. I have about 7000 data points, depending on the species. I would like to allow interactions between one variable and the other ten variables, and I would also like to include quadratic responses.

Is this possible? From what I gather looking at the R help and the vignette for this package, it is not, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: You can, but I doubt the algorithm would know how to handle it properly - you should only consider (unless you really, *really* know what you are doing) only the interaction terms first for deletion and once a variable is not included in an interaction then it can be considered for removal from the model. Hence the idea of all subsets is not as easily applied here as not all subsets would make sense. Also, adding all those interactions, plus quadratic terms sounds a lot like data dredging to me...

Comment: ...and to give you the rope and a loaded gun, look at `model.frame()` to extract the variables used in your model formula and `model.matrix()` to convert this into the design matrix. Hang / shoot yourself away...

Comment: Thanks Gavin. I am not so clear on your answer though, could you elaborate? I see your point about data dredging as well, which is not my goal. My goal is to  explain each vars' relationship, and determine if interaction effects exist. I have made univariate models,  additive models, and interaction mods: ~var1 +var2 + var1:var2. Quadratic responses are logical based on ecology, and best fit the data. I wanted to include a complete model as well, to see what level of deviance would be explained, and to see if the relationships remained the same, for completeness.

Comment: There is an issue here; if you want a quadratic effect of `x` you need `x` and `x^2` as variables to remain *in the model*, you don't want to consider a subset without `x` if `x^2` is in the subset. Likewise, if you have an interaction `x:y`, you should also have `x` and `y` as main effects in that subset, it probably doesn't make much sense to fit a subset without those main effects if the interaction is present. I doubt **bestglm** or **leaps** is that flexible that it can do the right thing with such terms, so you have to be careful. 1/2

Comment: if you use `model.frame(form, data)`, it will create a data frame with the model variables included. Pass this to `model.matrix()` with the formula for the full model and it will convert the quadratic terms and the interactions into actual variables in a model matrix. Remove the intercept column if you want. Pass this as argument `x` (or `X`, I forget which) of `bestglm()` and now it will  fit all subsets of those variables. `model.matrix()` is a neat way to go from the formula specification to the actual design matrix you want. 2/2

Comment: Finally, if you have 10 predictors (x2 for the quadratics) and interactions, you are going to explode the number of model subsets that the algorithm needs to wade through, and many of those will be redundant for the reasons I mentioned in comment 1/2 above.

Comment: I totally get your point about the rope and the gun now. Too bad, since I think the delete-d CV is a better test of a model than comparing AIC in a stepwise GLM. Loving life, I think I will forgo this particular avenue. Thanks for your help.